# rMBP random unexpected shutdown

Tags: macos, shutdown

Recently I'm facing random unexpected shutdown on rMBP mid-2014. I've clean installed the Yosemite with clean user and issue still continues. Apple online support suggested to work on Safe Mode and it didn't shutdown.

P.S.: I was working on Brackets code editor (http://brackets.io) when the first unexpected shutdown happened.

I inferred there is an issue with Intel Iris Pro, so I decide to delete the following kext file and the device didn't shutdown

```
AppleIntelBDWGraphics.kext
AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer.kext
AppleIntelBDWGraphicsGLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelBDWGraphicsVADriver.bundle
AppleIntelBDWGraphicsVAME.bundle
AppleIntelHD3000Graphics.kext
AppleIntelHD3000GraphicsGA.plugin
AppleIntelHD3000GraphicsGLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelHD3000GraphicsVADriver.bundle
AppleIntelHD4000Graphics.kext
AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsVADriver.bundle
AppleIntelHD5000Graphics.kext
AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsGLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsVADriver.bundle
AppleIntelHDGraphics.kext
AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB.kext
AppleIntelHDGraphicsGA.plugin
AppleIntelHDGraphicsGLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelHDGraphicsVADriver.bundle
```

So what are your thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please avoid asking questions such as "share your thoughts" because that is an open-ended, non-specific question.  Try to be as specific as possible and paste any errors you received.  That will give you the best chance on getting a good answer to your problem.  See [ask] for how to ask good questions.  - From Review -.

Comment: We need to get the shutdown cause.  In Terminal, issue the command `syslog | grep -i "shutdown cause" and post the output

Comment: @Kirkian N. - DId you find out what the issue was?

Answer (score 1):

I sent my laptop to two service centres and they said there is not any hardware issues. So I decided to clean install Mac OS X without installing any additional software but the problem still occurs.

Note: I also installed Windows 10 using bootcamp, the machine works without any unexpected shutdown issues.

I got this console log (http://pastebin.com/irLDsEhB), maybe these lines can help you identify this annoying issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that a hardware issue is causing the panics.  You can try booting the laptop while holding the D key, this will run a quick diagnostic.

Next step would be to bring it in for service, they'll run better diagnostics to see its condition, and send it out for repair.